# How to attach a a Java agent to an already running VM instance

Tags: java, classloader, virtual-machine, attach-api

I am trying to attach a *Java agent* to a running *Java* instance using the attach API. The problem I am getting is when I check a process id of an already running Java process in Windows Task Manager and hard code it into the program attaching the java agent. Nothing happens. Is it so that we cannot attach a Java agent to an already running process.

I went through the [dynamic agent loading tutorial](http://dhruba.name/2010/02/07/creation-dynamic-loading-and-instrumentation-with-javaagents/) it works fine but the only problem I see is, it detects the **VM** instance and dynamically attaches the *Java agent* to it. This instance none other than the one in which the current program for doing so is being launched.

Here requirement is to attach a Java agent to a already running **VM** instance like **JMonitor** and other analysis tools does. How to proceed kindly provide some direction.